# Flutter gstatic canvaskit CORS error when running locally in Chrome. No error on local linux run

Tags: flutter, cors

When I try to run flutter locally on chrome I get following error:

`Rejecting promise with error: TypeError: Failed to fetch TypeError: Failed to fetch`

**In chrome console:**

```
Access to fetch at 'https://gstatic.com/flutter-canvaskit/7572fe5b922634eb20b8ec4ad65646e6a356feb4/canvaskit.wasm' 
from origin 
'http://localhost:40487' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set 
the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Works fine when ran on linux desktop.
This `URL` is not something I am using in my code. Not sure where this request is made
[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

**Following things did not work:**

- try loading same flutter url in another browser - done
- Turn off vpn and add block protection - done
- Try disabling security of web browser by passing flag in flutter run  WORKED
- Html renderer doesn’t work
- Disable url request
- Check if Django server has flutter as allowed hosts - yes
- Restart Django server by downloading new images - done
- Try deploying flutter to firebase. If it works on firebase, then probably canvaskit doesnt work on http urls - It gives same error
- Try commenting out pacakge   - import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

  - Still same error
- Invalidate cache and restart android studio - Done